# OpenLayers 4 and automatic label placement

Tags: label, openlayers

I am looking for the best approach hook into OpenLayers 4 in order to run an automatic label placement algorithm depending on the zoom level so there is minimal overlapping of the text.

Currently, on a VectorLayer, an Icon is used to draw the background of the label with a leader line to the anchor point. A Style is used to specify the text that goes on top of the Icon.

I already know which algorithm I want to use, what is missing the correct approach with regards to OpenLayers 4. I am not interested in clustering or label decluttering.